# "Don't cast a nullable value to a non nullable type" in Map when converting JSON to object

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I just tried out the [very_good_analysis](https://pub.dev/packages/very_good_analysis) package which includes also the [cast_nullable_to_non_nullable](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/cast_nullable_to_non_nullable.html) lint rule.

And here is the code that gaves me the linter warning (initially, all casts look the the cast of `a`. Variables `b` and `c` are just showing what else I tried):

```dart
@immutable
class Foo {
  Foo.fromJson(Map<String, int> json):
    a = json['a'] as int, // Don't cast a nullable value to a non nullable type. (cast_nullable_to_non_nullable
    b = (json['b'] as int?)!, // Unnecessary cast
    c = json['c']! as int; // Unnecessary cast

  final int a;
  final int b;
  final int c;
}
```

So what is the correct way to convert this JSON map to a `Foo` object? And with correct I mean there are no warnings when using the `very_good_analysis` lints. Thanks a lot!

### Edit

I found a working solution:

```dart
@immutable
class Foo {
  Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    a = json['a'] as int, 
    b = json['b'] as int, 
    c = json['c'] as int;

  final int a;
  final int b;
  final int c;
}
```

But can you please explain **why** `Map<String, int>` does not work and `Map<String, dynamic>` works? Is this a bug in the linter rule?

Comment: Looking up a value in a map returns a nullable type, so `json['c']` returns an `int?`. When you use the null assertion operator `!` on a value of type `int?` you get back a value of type `int` instead (or it throws an exception if you had null). You are then casting a value which is already an `int` as `int`. Hence unnecessary cast.

Comment: Similarly with `(json['b'] as int?)!` remember `json['b']` returns an `int?` so you are casting an `int?` as `int?` which is unnecessary.

Comment: With `json['a'] as int` the preferred approach here is to use `!` instead of casting.

Comment: As for why it works with `dynamic`, remember that `dynamic` means any type whatsoever, and you want to convert a `dynamic` value to an `int`, but unlike with converting from `int?` to `int`, a `!` isn't going to get you to an `int`. Casting is the only way to get there with the available type information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like that rule is just there to encourage using the `!` operator over casting with `as`. This works for me with the `very_good_analysis` lints enabled:

```
class Foo {
  Foo.fromJson(Map<String, int> json)
      : a = json['a']!,
        b = json['b']!,
        c = json['c']!;

  final int a;
  final int b;
  final int c;
}
```

As for why you didn't get a warning with `Map<String, dynamic>`: that lint is written to not fire for `dynamic`. You can see it in the source [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/blob/a91fbd6ddabbb1b777bdfae80d0aada3c3785333/lib/src/rules/cast_nullable_to_non_nullable.dart#L73). It's probably debatable but I would consider that the correct behavior. If you're using `dynamic` in your code you're already telling the language to effectively turn off compile-time type checking and just trust you instead.